# Why does my code show different output on different compiler?

Tags: c

This is a code to calculate nth fibonacci number.

Code :

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main(){
    int n;
    printf("N: ");
    scanf("%d", &n);
    long double third, first = 0 , second = 1;
    for(int i=1 ; i<=n ; i++){
        third = first + second;
        first = second;
        second = third;
    }
    printf("The result is : %Lf", third);
    return 0;
}
```

This code shows correct output when I run it on an online compiler i.e. https://www.onlinegdb.com/online_c_compiler but when I run this on MS Visual Studio Code, it returns wrong output.

Output of https://www.onlinegdb.com/online_c_compiler :

```
N: 10
The result is : 89.000000
```

Output from MS Visual Code :

```
N: 10
The result is : -0.000000
```

I carefully checked the code I used on both the compilers was exactly same.
I think the code is correct but there is some problem in my MS Visual Studio Code.
What could be the reason of this unknown behavior?

Comment: How are you providing the input?  You don't check the value returned by scanf, so `n` may not be what you expect.

Comment: Hardcode `n` to make sure.

Comment: Not Visual Studio, but a MS Visual C compilation gives the correct answer. Note that MS VC does not support `long double` which it treats as `double`.

Comment: @EugeneSh. How to do that? I am not aware of it sorry.

Comment: with `int n = 10;`

Comment: @WeatherVane ```int n = 10;``` is not working

Comment: There is no obvious reason, perhaps you are not running the code you think, or didn't compile it.

Comment: @WeatherVane Changing the datatype to double worked, thanks!. Can you suggest something from where I can learn this topic, I am new to programming.

Comment: MS makes up its own rules.

Comment: From the comments under a deleted answer, the size 12 for `long double` shows that it is implemented by your compiler (otherwise it would be 8).

Comment: @WeatherVane How does the size affect the output?

Comment: I don't know, sorry, my MS compiler version simply uses a normal `double` of size 8 for `long double`, but as a wild shot you could try `%lf` instead of `%Lf`.

Comment: @WeatherVane Changing the datatype to double instead of long double worked fine but changing the format specifier doesn't work, I guess my version of MS Code doesn't know about long double.

Comment: "Visual Studio Code" isn't a compiler, it's an editor that can be used with many different compilers and implementations.  Can you say more about the environment where your code failed?  What OS and version, what compiler is VSCode invoking, and so on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, you should always check the return value of [scanf](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_scanf.htm).

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(){
    int n;
    printf("N: ");
    if (scanf("%d", &n) != 1) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error in scanf");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    long double third, first = 0 , second = 1;
    for (int i = 1 ; i <= n ; i++) {
        third = first + second;
        first = second;
        second = third;
    }
    printf("The result is : %Lf\n", third);
    return 0;
}
```

The C language standard has several areas that are implementation-defined, which means that each compiler implementation is free to choose how it will behave in those situations, and to document how it will behave.
The C standard states also that the behaviour of certain statements are undefined - which means that the compiler implementers have no information about how to provide correct behaviour - since there is no definition for ‘correct’ in these cases.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the relevance of the last paragraph.  Are there instances of undefined or implementation-defined behavior in the linked program?  I didn't see any.  (Except that there will be UB if `scanf` failed, because then `n` will be used uninitialized - but I think it's unlikely that this is what happened.)